# Which kind of views style to use JS image effect?

Tags: views, 6, javascript

I wonder which kind of views style do I choose to make a page like it can be done with masonry.

Actually I use Susy 2, and the [example](http://www.zell-weekeat.com/masonry-with-susy/) present items in `div`, actually I get items in a `ul` via views. Which is better?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Views Fluid Grid - jQuery Masonry](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fluidgrid) module.